# Mpdf color format issue while converting svg image to mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf for convert SVG image to pdf but I got a transparent color issue while converting SVG to pdf. here is the code

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8','default_font' => 'dejavusans']);
$html = '<style>@page { sheet-size: '.$width.'mm '.$height.'mm; }</style><div 
     style="position: absolute; left:0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;">
     <img src="'.$svgurl.'" width="'.$width.'mm" height="'.$height.'mm"/></div>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

look at the both images one is original and one is pdf image.[image]

[image]

Comment: Your SVG image might be using an unsupported feature, for instance in the color depth. I can't tell because the original in your question is a JPG image.

Comment: [Here](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/images.html) it says: *Debugging Errors:* If you are having trouble with images not displaying correctly, set the variable `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true.`. Further down it also says what is supported and not supported in SVG images.